# I recently learned I'm allergic to potassium dicromate or chromium

Tags: safety, medicinal-chemistry

are eye drops with inactive ingredients called potassium chloride or sodium chloride the same as potassium dichromate and should I stop using those eye drops?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Right now I can divide your question into two parts: "are eye drops with inactive ingredients called potassium chloride or sodium chloride the same as potassium dichromate?" This part is unfortunately unclear. The same, as in what? Of course dichromate ion isn't the same as chloride, so...This leaves the question as a very puzzling one. The other part is "should I stop using those eye drops?" This part is unfortunately off-topic here. We don't answer questions that *seek medical advice*.

Answer (score 7):

Allergic reactions against dichromates are not uncommon.

However, dichromates and chlorides, are two pairs of shoes. Really different ones, like stiletto heels and moon boots ;-)

To my knowledge, there are no eye drops containing potassium dichromate!

The sodium chloride that you mentioned is nothing but table salt. Isotonic solutions of sodium chloride are very common in all sorts of medical applications, like rinsing of lenses, intravenous infusions, and so on. To my knowledge, allergic reactions on these solutions are not known.

To sum it up: I am not a medical doctor, and you might want to contact your ophthalmologist, but as a chemist with some experience in medical chemistry, I can assure that

- dichromates and chlorides are not the same
- allergic reactions to physiological saline are not known